# PDF reader for single user

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-viewer

I am looking for a **lightweight** PDF reader for single user which **has** these features:

- View mode: full screen, single page and continuous scrolling. Can zoom.
- Virtual printer
- Text search, bookmarks and last page view
- Multi tabs, remembering last open tabs is a plus
- Can add custom hotkeys
- Available for Windows

Some addition features to consider, sort by important:

- Right click on selected text to google
- Can make bookmarks from non-bookmarked PDF
- Can export images
- Can deal with djvu format
- Have ORC feature (scan text to make it searchable)
- Available for Linux

Things I definitely don't need:

- Fill form
- Annotating and commenting
- Sharing and collaborating
- Securing my files (I even don't install any antivirus software, because they are useless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For years now, I have used [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) and can highly recommend it.

- View mode: full screen, single page and continuous scrolling. Can zoom.  **Yes**
- Virtual printer **Yes**
- Text search, bookmarks and last page view **Yes**
  (I particularly like that you can search through the current document, all open documents, or all PDF documents in a given directory.
- Multi tabs, remembering last open tabs is a plus **Yes to both**
- Can add custom hotkeys **Yes**
- Available for Windows **Yes**

And for some of your nice-to-have features:

- Right click on selected text to Google **Yes**
- Can make bookmarks from non-bookmarked PDF **Yes**
- Can export images **Available in PRO version**
- Can deal with djvu format **No**
- Have ORC feature (scan text to make it searchable) **Yes**
- Available for Linux **No**

Well,  it hits most of your points & could can try it so see about the others. Plus, it is free.

For many years it has been the top [recommended PDF reader at Gizmo's TechSupportAlert](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-non-adobe-pdf-reader.htm)

[image: Screenshot of PDF-XChange Viewer]

Comment: I love this software. All yeses for what I need and only two noes for additional features. I have add some information to your answer. By the way, here is the page about [virtual printer](http://www.tracker-software.com/knowledgebase/272-How-do-I-create-multiple-unique-PDF-XChange-Printers)

Comment: Don't have time to write another answer, but I would also recommend using [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/). Especially if you are in Linux OS

Answer (score 3):

I have found a **free PDF Viewer** [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) which is lightweight and allow you to view multiple types of document like **djvu, tiff, PDF, XPS,** etc.

It has following features:

- View PDFs,
- view thumbnails,
- search,
- view document indexes,
- print documents, and
- encrypted document viewing.

And you want the application available for **Windows** and **Linux** both platforms than Evince is available for both.

Comment: Could you please detail yes/no for all bullets of the question? Thanks!