# Linux PDF reader that shows annotations

Tags: linux, pdf-viewer

I am looking for a lightweight PDF reader that **shows** annotations. I do not need to be able to add my own annotations. Evince only shows one type of comments - it does not show removed text or replaced text. Okular seems to have these options but has a whole lot of large dependencies. Any tips?

Command line parsing is also an option, if that turns out to be the only lightweight option.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, you might consider using a Windows PDF viewer under Wine. See my answer for the best free option http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17212/pdf-reader-for-single-user/17230#17230

Comment: You might also try installing the  Chrome browser for Linux as that handles PDF, so __might__ / will probably show annotations.  https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/ (it auto-detects your o/s in order to offer you a download)

Answer (score 2):

[FoxIt](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) PDF reader has a Linux version and say that it can

> read, create, sign, and annotate (comment on) PDF documents and fill
>   out PDF forms.

It would seem to follow logically that any program which can create annotations can also sign them.

Alas, I have no current access to a Linux box, but if you follow my logic, then give it a try.

See specifically http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/collaborate-share.php

[image]

> Provide feedback to documents through annotation and text markup
>   tools.

Answer (score 2):

The modern Browser seem to be able to open PDF and show annotations.
Can confirm for Chrome, heared for Firefox.
You can just move the PDF on it.

Comment: In my case, after trying several dedicated PDF readers on linux, **firefox** ended up being the one that allowed me to view annotation text.

Comment: genius, thanks a ton, it worked like a champion.

Answer (score 0):

[Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) shows annotations [since 2010](http://blogs.igalia.com/carlosgc/2010/07/26/adding-new-annotations-with-evince/) or so. As you mentioned yourself, there is a catch: Many annotation types exist and there are some which are not yet supported (as of mid 2016). Check [this bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=168304) for more information and links to other bug reports which track some annotation types.

However, since you posted [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=583377) got fixed which may fix the issue you saw.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try our free PDF reader for Linux, PDF Studio Viewer:
https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/download/

It can render / display any type of annotations contained in a PDF document. It will show Replace Text and Insert Text which are called text markup annotations.